# Show that $R_{\mu\nu}=fg_{\mu\nu}$ (Ricci and metric tensors) and $\dim(M)\geq 3$ then $f$ is constant

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

I need to prove that given the Ricci and metric tensors $R_{\mu\nu}=fg_{\mu\nu}$ and $\dim(M)\geq 3$ then $f$ is constant.

I tried to use some identities but I end up with some sort of a proof without using the hypothesis of the dimension so I must be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the second Bianchi identity $$\nabla_i R_{jklm} + \nabla_j R_{kilm} + \nabla_k R_{ijlm} = 0$$ and contract with $g^{jl}g^{km}$ to get

$$ \nabla_i R^j_j = 2 \nabla^j R_{ij}.$$

If $R_{ij} = fg_{ij}$ this is $f_i g^j _j = 2 f_i$. Since $g^j_j = \delta^j_j = n$, we get $(n-2)f_i = 0$ (where $n$ is the dimension); so as long as $n\ne 2$ we see that $\nabla f = 0$.